# C++ unqualified-id, other posts not helping

Tags: c++, linux, compilation, g++

I'm working on a linux machine and using g++ to compile a .cpp file. I keep getting the following errors:

```
hillClimbing.cpp:6: error: expected unqualified-id before â[â token
hillClimbing.cpp:7: error: expected unqualified-id before â[â token
hillClimbing.cpp:8: error: expected unqualified-id before â[â token
hillClimbing.cpp:17: error: expected unqualified-id before â[â token
```

I have been looking at similar posts on this site but they don't seem to match my problem, and I'm unable to fix it. Here is the .cpp file:

```
#include <utility>
#include "evaluateParams.h"

using namespace std;

    double[] optimizeParams(EvaluateParams eval, pair<double, double> ranges[], double ss[], double a, double e, bool hillClimb, bool ascent);
    double[] initParams(pair<double, double> ranges[]);
    double[] climbHill(double pos[], double stepSize[], double epsilon, bool findMax);

    evaluateParams evalMethod;
    double accel;

    //eval/evalMethod: defines method used to compare a set of params
    //ranges: list of ranges that each parameter can take
    //ppp: points per parameter, the number of points initialized is ppa^ranges.size()
    //hillClimb: indicates weather to enact the hillClimb algorithm or simply randomize
    double[] optimizeParams(evaluateParams eval, pair<double, double> ranges[], double ss[], double a, double e, bool hillClimb, bool ascent){
            evalMethod = eval;
            accel = a;

            double paramValues[] = initParams(ranges);
            if(hillClimb){
                    paramValues = climbHill(paramValues[i], ss, e, ascent);
            }
            return paramValues;
    }

    double[] initParams(pair<double, double> ranges[]){
            double values[ranges.size()];
            for(int j = 0; j < ranges.size(); j++){
                    double min = ranges[i].first;
                    double max = ranges[i].second;
                    double r = ((double) rand() / (RAND_MAX));
                    r *= max-min;
                    r += min;
                    values[i][j]=r;
            }
            return values;
    }

    double[] climbHill(double pos[], double stepSize[], double epsilon, bool findMax){
            double candidate[] = [-accel, -1/accel, 0, 1/accel, accel];
            while(true){ //may need to switch to a timer in case points get stuck
                    double init = eval.evaluate(pos);
                    for(int i = 0; i < pos.size(); i++){
                            int best = -1;
                            double bestEval = -1 * numeric_limits<double>::max();
                            for(int j = 0; j < candidate.size(); j++){
                                    pos[i] = pos[i] + stepSize[i]*candidate[j];
                                    double temp = eval.evaluate(tempPos);
                                    pos[i] = pos[i] - stepSize[i]*candidate[j];
                                    if(temp > bestScore){
                                            bestEval = temp;
                                            best = j;
                                    }
                            }
                            if(findMax){
                                    pos[i] = pos[i] + stepSize[i] * candidate[best];
                            }
                            else{
                                    pos[i] = pos[i] - stepSize[i] * candidate[best];
                            }
                            if(candidate[best] != 0){
                                    stepSize[i] = stepSize[i] * candidate[best];
                            }
                    }
                    if(eval.evaluate(pos)-init < epsilon){
                            return pos;
                    }
            }
    }
```

and here is the .h file:

```
class evaluateParams{
    public:
            evaluateParams(){}
            virtual double evaluate(double[]);

};
```

most of the other posts i've seen were fixed by adding a ';' at the end of the header file, which i've done.

Comment: You cannot return C arrays. You should probably use `std::vector`.

Comment: `double values[ranges.size()];` is illegal; array sizes must be known at compile-time.  (Some compilers have an extension to allow this, but it leads to questionable behaviour in more complicated scenarios).

Comment: there's also numerous major problems with `climbHill`, this looks like someone has copy-pasted Java code and changed a couple of things

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arrays in C++ are declared differently than they are declared in Java. Moreover, C++ built-in arrays aren't dynamically sized. You should probably replace all uses of `double[]` by `std::vector<double>`: this is the C++ way of specifying a dynamically sized array of objects.

Answer (score 1):

Functions may not have the return type defined as an array> So these declarations are invalid

```
double[] optimizeParams(EvaluateParams eval, pair<double, double> ranges[], double ss[], double a, double e, bool hillClimb, bool ascent);
double[] initParams(pair<double, double> ranges[]);
double[] climbHill(double pos[], double stepSize[], double epsilon, bool findMax);
```

They have to be declared as

```
double * optimizeParams(EvaluateParams eval, pair<double, double> ranges[], double ss[], double a, double e, bool hillClimb, bool ascent);
double * initParams(pair<double, double> ranges[]);
double * climbHill(double pos[], double stepSize[], double epsilon, bool findMax);
```

Also as you return pointers to the first elements of local arrays then the behaviour of the program is undefined.

Also this statement is invalid

```
double paramValues[] = initParams(ranges);
```

Arrays may not be initialized such a way.

Comment: It's true that a function can't be declared to return `double[]`. It's less clear that the fix is to change it to `double*`.

Comment: @Keith Thompson He is trying to return an array.

Comment: Understood. He can't do that. Returning a pointer is not the same thing.

Comment: @Keith Thompson But it is correct. I showed correct function declarations instead of invalid.

Comment: It's correct only in the sense that it compiles. I can change the `double[]` to `void` and remove the `return` statements and have something that compiles. As you've already acknowledged, the resulting code is incorrect because it returns a pointer to the first element of a local array.

Comment: @Keith Thompson You may not change double[] to void because it will be a totally different design that has nothing common with the code..

Comment: A function returning an array would look like `double func(...)[]`.  Doing this actually causes Clang to give an error that you can't have an array as the return type as opposed to *expected unqualified-id*.

Comment: Agreed. Changing `double[]` to `double*` is not significantly better. You have to redesign the code anyway (probably using `std::vector` or something similar).

Comment: @ghostofstandardspast: A C++ function returning an array would not look like anything, because it doesn't exist.

Comment: @KeithThompson, Does it not being permitted mean the parsing syntax doesn't exist as well? I mean both GCC and Clang change their errors, so I would figure there's *something* about that syntax.

Comment: @ghostofstandardspast: Very interesting point. You're right, `double func()[]` is not a syntax error, but it does violate a "shall" requirement. (The only likely practical effect is the wording of the error message.)

Comment: @ghostofstandardspas According to the C++ Standard "Functions shall not have a return type of type array"

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, Yes, I realize that, I was just assuming it was something more like having an incompatible return type on an overriding function, where it still overrides the function, but then runs into an explicit rule saying the return type doesn't work. In that sense, there would still be a "correct" way to define a function with an array as the return type, but then run into a problem because of the explicit rule that you can't have an array as the return type. My thoughts were only based on the error messages, though.